# UI not closing in sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use a UI to show a loading screen.  A user triggers a function which opens a UI which displays a loading message then executes some code and after that's finished closes the UI.  I have a sample spreadsheet with my attempt at this which can be found here: https://docs.google.com/a/ucera.org/spreadsheets/d/1CtnoIoqYCYqVjf7aCd7BG4AOMYNNt7Ji6Q43op3yXeI/edit#gid=0.  I manually trigger the "Test Loading" function from the "Script Center Menu" and the UI pops up with the loading message, it executes the code and then the UI is supposed to close but it doesn't.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UiApp has been deprecated and should not be used.   Try using htmlService instead.  Here is the documentation.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers

You need to initiate the function you want to run from the html file using 
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(close).myFunction()", and 
Basically the close function should include google.script.host.close();